# List VSI with not exist tag, server return {"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I use a non-existent tag to list VSI in api https://api.softlayer.com/mobile/v3.1/. server returns `200 {"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}`.

Normally, server should return 200 with `[]`. If there is an error in the response, the return code shouldn't be 200.

Here is the details:

> 2018/10/19 10:33:59 [DEBUG] Request URL:  GET https://api.softlayer.com/mobile/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.jsonobjectFilter=%7B%22virtualGuests%22%3A%7B%22tagReferences%22%3A%7B%22tag%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22in%22%2C%22options%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22data%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%5B%22not_exist_tag%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&objectMask=mask%5Bid%2C+globalIdentifier%2C+hostname%2C+hourlyBillingFlag%2C+domain%2C+fullyQualifiedDomainName%2C+status.name%2C+powerState.name%2C+activeTransaction%2C+datacenter.name%2C+account.id%2C+maxCpu%2C+maxMemory%2C+primaryIpAddress%2C+primaryBackendIpAddress%2C+privateNetworkOnlyFlag%2C+dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag%2C+createDate%2C+modifyDate%2C+billingItem%5BorderItem%5Bid%2Corder.userRecord%5Busername%5D%5D%2C+recurringFee%5D%2C+notes%2C+tagReferences.tag.name%5D&resultLimit=0%2C100
>       2018/10/19 10:33:59 [DEBUG] Parameters:
>       2018/10/19 10:34:01 [DEBUG] Status Code:  200
>       2018/10/19 10:34:01 [DEBUG] Response:  {"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Answer (score 0):

The error that you got is because you are using double brackets in the ¨value¨ attribute of the object filter.

I suggest you to use like below example:

```
"value":["not_exist_tag"]
```

Or you can try using the below rest api call:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"tagReferences":{"tag":{"name":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["not_exist_tag"]}]}}}}}
```

And the status code for a "internal error" should not be 200, this is a SoftLayer api issue, it was already reported.